# change Jquery object into <ul><li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery object :-

```
        (function ($) {
            var menu = [{
                title: Main1",
                href: "/"
            }, {
                title: "Main2",
                href: "/main2",
                items: [{
                    title: "SubMain2_1",
                    href: "/subMain2_1"
                }, {
                    title: "SubMain2_2",
                    href: "/subMain2_2"
                }]
            }, {
                title: "Main3",
                href: "/main3",
                items: [{
                    title: "SubMain3_1",
                    href: "/subMain3_1"
                }, {
                    title: "SubMain3_2",
                    href: "/subMain3_2",
                    items: [{
                        title: "SubSubMain3_1",
                        href: "/SubSubMain3_2"
                    }, {
                        title: "SubSubMain3_2",
                        href: "/subSubMain3_2"
                    }]
                }, {
                    title: "SubMain3_3",
                    href: "/subMain3_3"
                }]
            }, {
                title: "Main4",
                href: "/main4"
            }];
        });
```

and I wish to change this into

```
   <ul>
     <li class="Main"><a href="/">Main1</a></li>
     <li class="Main"><a href="/main2">Main2</a></li>
     <ul>
        <li class="Sub"><a href="/subMain2_1">SubMain2_1</a></li>
        <li class="Sub"><a href="/subMain2_2">SubMain2_2</a></li>
     </ul>
     <li class="Main"><a href="/main3">Main3</a></li>
     <ul>
        <li class="Sub"><a href="/subMain3_1">SubMain3_1</a></li>
        <li class="Sub"><a href="/subMain3_2">SubMain3_2</a></li>
        <ul>
           <li class="SubSub"><a href="/subSubMain3_1">SubSubMain3_1</a></li>
           <li class="SubSub"><a href="/subSubMain3_2">SubSubMain3_2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li class="Sub"><a href="/subMain3_3">SubMain3_3</a></li>
     </ul>
     <li class="Main"><a href="/">Main4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? We could write the code for you, but it's always better to see that you made an effort first...

Comment: That's not a "jQuery object".

Comment: @Toiletduck I was thinking of a foreach loop, however I have no idea of how to achieve that in javascript and write <ul><li>.  THis is the first time I am trying something similar

Comment: I would start with https://github.com/jonnyreeves/jquery-Mustache

Comment: @Johann Check out Karl Andre's answer. It's spot on - that's exactly what you need to do. Note that you need to be using jQuery for it to work though. Not just javascript.

Comment: yeah its amazing, the kind of solution I was searching for.  I added it in a normal HTML page, with JQuery 2.0.3.min, but I am not seeing the menu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a recursive function that call itself everytime there is a array `items`:

```
$('body').append(fnMenu(menu));

function fnMenu(el){
    var ul = $('<ul>')
    $.each(el, function(){
        var li = $('<li>')
        li.append($('<a>', {text : this.title, href : this.href}));           
        ul.append(li)
        if(this.items) li.after(fnMenu(this.items)); 
    })
    return ul;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2hP9K/

Comment: That's a good one! +1

Comment: +1 For just being awesomeness personified.

Comment: This is amazing.  For some reason its not working in my html page though.

Comment: @Johann mind to show me your page? If you are working locally, can you make a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: Hi Karl, is this fine? http://pastebin.com/v6eGDwvb

Comment: @Johann it is perfect, The problem is that you are not waiting until the DOM is ready. `<body>` doesnt exist when you rune your code. You can put your script tag after the close body tag or apply the change i made here : http://pastebin.com/DscUGvv2. Look where the `$('body').append()` is.

Comment: Yep that works!  Brilliant stuff Karl, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a reference and continue.

```
    var  ul = $("<ul>");
        for (var i = 0, l = obj1.length; i < l; ++i) {
            ul.append("<li><a href='" + obj1[i].href + "'>" + obj1[i].title + "</a></li>");
        }
        $("#results").append(ul);    // add the list to the DOM
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrbe/fMvf7/1/)

Comment: thanks harsha, will take it from here

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
c = 0; 
function arrayer(rows,classe){
    c++;
    html = "";
    foreach(rows as row){
        html.='<ul class="'+classe+'">';
        if(row['items']!=""){ 
            html.='<li>';
            html.=arrayer(row['items'],'Sub');
            html.='</li>';
        }else{
            html.='<li class="'+row['title']+'" href="'+row['href']+'">'+classe+' '+c+'</li>';
        }
        html.='</ul>';
        return html;
    }
}
```

Call:

```
html_menu = arrayer(menu,'Main');
$('div.menu').append(html_menu);
```